# Flutter:My ScrollWidget is scrolling down but my SUBMIT and CANCEL Raised Buttons are getting invisible or not shown

Tags: forms, flutter, scrollview

Error showing is

> Invalid Matrix

I want my submit button and Cancel button as this is Form submission in flutter
My ScrollWidget is scrolling down but my SUBMIT and CANCEL  Raised Buttons are getting invisible or not shown.
the code is  as follows:

```
   body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
                 Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        autofocus: false,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_pin),
                          labelText: 'CompanyName',
                          hintText: 'Type the company Name',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                         autofocus: false,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone_android),
                          labelText: 'ModelName',
                          hintText: 'Type the Model Name',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
                
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'SerielNumber',
                          hintText: 'Type the Seriel Number',
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.view_headline),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Color(0xff476cfb),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                        child: TextField(
                      maxLines: null,
                      autofocus: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.place),
                          labelText: 'Cancel',

                      ),
                    ),
             
                 
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Color(0xff476cfb),
                    onPressed: () {
                      uploadPic(context);
                    },

                    elevation: 4.0,
                    splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    
                    child: TextField(
                      maxLines: null,
                      autofocus: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.place),
                        labelText: 'Submit',

                      ),
                    ),
                                       
                  ),

                ],
              )

            ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, I am having a hard time copying it.

Comment: Ok just suggest me How can I scroll  even with a body:builder(

Comment: Ok just suggest me How can I scroll  even with a         body: Builder(
        builder: (context) =>  Container(
          child: Column(    as I have more list items before submit button etc and SUBMIT btton is not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your RaisedButton's Child. TextField must have bounded width.
you can use Text widget or Container widget as child of RaisedButton and use Row as child of Container to set title and icon like code below:

```
RaisedButton(
                  color: Color(0xff476cfb),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('submit'),
                      Icon(Icons.place),
                    ],
                  )),
                ),
```